# Replace EditText selection

Tags: java, android, string, replace, android-edittext

How can I replace the selected text with something in android's edittext?
For example:

```
Default Text
```

Assume "Default" is selected now.
I want to replace it with !boldDefault.
How can I do it? I tried using get selection method but I couldn't replace it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `EditText` currently has text selected, you can access the start and end points of the selection like so:

```
int start = editText.getSelectionStart();
int end = editText.getSelectionEnd();
```

You can access the `EditText`'s `Editable` text like this:

```
Editable edit = et.getText();
```

Now you can replace anything inside that `Editable` using the `replace()` method:

```
String newText = "this will replace the current selection";
edit.replace(start, end, newText);
```

Once you've done that, you probably want to change the selection so that you don't have part of your new text still selected:

```
editText.setSelection(start + newText.length());
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. This is exactly what i was looking for.